# Json don't receive data from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

Hi I pass an array from php to another to used it on a javascript function using json, but not return nothing, gives me "null" all time.

php code

```
function getParents($id_child){
include "conexion.php";
$query = $conexion->query('SELECT person_id FROM children WHERE children_id='.$id_child.';');
$query->execute();

while ($res = $query->fetch()) {
    $id_parents[] = $res[0]; //family_id
}
return $id_parents;
echo json_encode($id_parents);


}
getParents($_POST['id_child']);
```

Php who takes the json:

```
    <?php
$json_data=json_encode($id_parents);
?>
function sacarPadres(id_child){

    $.ajax({
            data:  {"id_child" : id_child,
            },
            url:   'php/functions_sql.php',
            type:  'post',
            success:  function(output) {

              }
    });
    var an_obj= "<?php echo $json_data;?>";
alert(an_obj); // always null 

}
<div id="form">
<FORM NAME=form1>
    <INPUT TYPE='button' NAME='myFamily' value='add new family' onclick="sacarPadres(70);">
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After return type everything is vanish

just `remove return type`

```
//return $id_parents;
  echo json_encode($id_parents);
```

**Updated**

```
function getParents($id_child){
include "conexion.php";
$query = $conexion->query('SELECT person_id FROM children WHERE children_id='.$id_child.';');
$query->execute();

while ($res = $query->fetch()) {
    $id_parents[] = $res[0]; //family_id
}

return json_encode($id_parents);


}
echo $val=getParents($_POST['id_child']);
```

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
            data:  {"id_child" : id_child,
            },
            url:   'php/functions_sql.php',
            type:  'post',
            success:  function(output) {
                      alert(output);//alert here
              }
    });
```

Comment: I just did, but the alert still gives me null, burt now php return the array why Javascript does not take it?

Comment: where is your `functions_sql.php` file??

Comment: in a folder called php, the route of the ajax it's correct

Comment: change this data:  `{"id_child" : id_child,
            },` to data:  `{id_child : id_child,
            },` remove quotes

Comment: It's the same result :S

Comment: check have your code enter into functions_sql.php or not?? also remove last semi column from your query

Comment: Yes the ajax is correct, send the data and the jquery returns the array correctly.

Comment: Yes I've also did it :s (I'm gonna change it in the question too)

Comment: I have to change something on the javascript part? because I'm still has the value null :(

Comment: Yes it return it! without  json, thank you o much *___*

Comment: O the last thing how can I do a loop with the output? is this an array?

Comment: The php return an array but `output` is a string, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

The `return` statement causes the program to exit the function. All statements after `return` will not be executed. Move `return` to the end of the function or remove at all.